# return an array of strings .net c# web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to c# and the whole .net platform so I'm struggling with a lot of what are probably pretty basic things. go easy on me. All I'm trying to do right now is return an array of json objects (as strings, obviously).

```
[HttpPost]
public string[] PostJsonString([FromBody] string[] arr)
    {

        return arr;

    }
```

And in Postman, I'm sending

```
[{"someProp":"someVal"},{ "aThing":"someOtherThing"}]
```

So painfully simple... Literally only trying to respond with the exact contents of the request body, but for some reason I get back an empty array. Does anyone have any idea why this might be? I've tried returning the array as a string with `str.toArray` but then I get back the object type, i.e. `"System.String[]"`. I just want a simple JSON response with the objects in an array.

Any tips are appreciated. Even if it's just pointing me to a helpful resource. I've exhausted all the relevant S/O questions and a) don't see one that quite addresses what i'm trying to accomplish, and b) have still tried some of the solutions to no avail.

Comment: your json doesn't represent a string array, its more like a dictionary or custom object.  A string array would be `["someProp", "someVal", "aThing", "someOtherThing"]`

Comment: ahhh. mkay. @Jonesopolis, i gotcha. so even though the json is technically a string (being that http doesn't actually know what an object is, right?), it still behaves as an object? is that correct?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon danke, herr Shannon. I've looked at it, but I guess I just didn't realize that the JSON was already behaving as objects when being sent via http.

Answer (score 2):

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PostJsonString([FromBody] string[] arr)
{
    return Json(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller will receive a *single string*

```
"[{\"someProp\":\"someVal\"},{ \"aThing\":\"someOtherThing\"}]"
```

Change the method's signature to

```
public string PostJsonString([FromBody] string arr)
```

When you want to work with the JSON array, I recommend using `JSON.net` (aka `Newtonsoft.Json`) and [JArray.Parse](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonArray.htm) or [JObject.Parse](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonObject.htm)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json
// ...
JArray a = JArray.Parse(json);
```

Comment: SUCCESS! Thanks, mate. `[HttpPost]
        public JArray PostJsonString([FromBody] string arr)
        {

            JArray a = JArray.Parse(arr);


            return a;

        }` also, i wasn't sending the array inside a string initially. i reformatted my request from `[json in here]` to `'[json in here]'`.  just a note for posterity. ;)